# android gif shared element transition

Tags: android, imageview, gif, shared-element-transition, fresco

I know how to make shared element transition for image. Is there a way we could do gif shared element transition? When we click on a gif, it pops up to be a fullscreen view. Or could we pause the gif, then do the shared element transition?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pause animations easily enough:

```
Animatable animatable = mSimpleDraweeView.getController().getAnimatable();
if (animatable != null) {
  animatable.stop();
}
```

Then later on you can do you transition. Note that Fresco requires usage of the ChangeBounds transition; you can't use the ChangeImageTransform transition.